# Add image in login screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am not able to add the image on the top with the Login text .How can I add my logo image on Login text area. Also can somebody please help me to add a free textafter the 3 buttons.
[image]

Here is my code for this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/jklogin4" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Username" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/close"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="Cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="  Enter  " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
            android:text="Password" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
            android:text="Signup" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Comment: `please help me to add a free textafter the 3 buttons` Do you want to add the text below three buttons or after 3 buttons ?

Comment: @Grishu after three buttons .Like free text with 3 long lines

Comment: You can add the `TextView` and provide the Text which you can define in your `String.xml` file in it below 3 buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out my below layout code in which i have added the image on top of the `TextView` and also added the `TextView` below the 3 `Buttons` as you need it.

> ```
>   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>          android:layout_width="match_parent"
>          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>          android:orientation="vertical"
>
> <RelativeLayout
>     android:id="@+id/register"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>     android:background="@drawable/jklogin4" >
>   <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView1"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>         android:text="Login"
>         android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView2"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
>         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
>         android:text="Username" />
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/editText1"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
>         android:ems="10" />
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/editText2"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
>         android:ems="10" />
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/close"
>         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
>         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
>         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>         android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
>         android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
>         android:text="Cancel" />
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/button1"
>         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
>         android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
>         android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
>         android:text="  Enter  " />
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView3"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
>         android:text="Password" />
>     <Button
>         android:id="@+id/button2"
>         style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
>         android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
>         android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
>         android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
>         android:text="Signup" />
> </RelativeLayout>
>   <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/text"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
>         android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
>         android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
>         android:layout_below="@+id/register"
>         android:text="ajsfoiahoihaoihaoifhasf hsohaoishdiuasgdouhasofhsaodfhosahoaisdfoashdfohsdfoih" />
>   </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Add `drawable top` attribute for your login TextView

i.e add this attribute

```
android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"  <-- Your drawable name
```

to this

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```